# Anchor link from another page, loads from anchor link only

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have two pages, when I link from page one to an anchor in page two it takes me to the right place, but none of the page before the anchor link is loaded. Both pages are php as I'm using an php menu

If i use

```
 <a href="pagetwo.php">
```

this loads the full page two as expected, no problem

but,

```
<a href="pagetwo.php#anchor1">
```

only loads the bottom half of page two, from the anchor1 id. If i refresh the page it remains the same.

I've done links to anchors before in html and no problem, is this an php issue or am I missing something?

I've spent most of day here searching previously asked questions, but nothing similar, if there is one please let me know.

Not sure if I should be tagging php?

Update, Inspected elements(firefox) and all code is there, but its, just not showing above anchor id. Same in Google and ie 8

Another update, saved both pages as html, no change....??

Deleted all php code...no change

Deleted all jquery..no change

Now this has to be something so simple that i'm missing!!

In Firefox problem remains

ie 8 does not work, but when you refresh shows whole page

chrome, loads whole page initially, but then only loads from anchor id

Double checked validation, 2 errors, now correct, still same

My wrapper is set to-

```
 .maincontainer {
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

When I change the overflow to visible the problem goes away, anchor links works perfectly.
But now page is runs on and on...

Now I've changed some bottom margin and padding settings and all works perfectly!

So I've kind of answered my own question....but..that leads me to two more questions!!

1. Why did the overflow hidden cause the anchor link to display like that?
2. I more or less solved this by using a process of elimination and then isolating certain elements in the html, which led me to the CSS.  How should you go about solving an problem like this?

Comment: `#anchor1` will take you to the element with the id of `anchor1`.
Do you have a link to a working example?

Comment: Thanks for reply, it does take you to the anchor1 id, but the rest of the page before anchor1 id is not showing